# IllegalStateException while starting up web app - Spring + Wicket

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, wicket

I am trying to run my webapp with Tomcat 7 but i am getting this exception:

GRAVE: Excepción arrancando filtro wicket.filter
**java.lang.IllegalStateException: bean of type [org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebApplication] not found**
    at org.apache.wicket.spring.SpringWebApplicationFactory.createApplication(SpringWebApplicationFactory.java:160)
    at org.apache.wicket.spring.SpringWebApplicationFactory.createApplication(SpringWebApplicationFactory.java:139)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.init(WicketFilter.java:308)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.init(WicketFilter.java:286)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4841)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5535)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

This is my web.xml:

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

```
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>       
        classpath:*/META-INF/persistence-context.xml,
        classpath:*/META-INF/service-context.xml,
        classpath:*/META-INF/web-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>configuration</param-name>
    <param-value>development</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>wicket.filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>applicationFactoryClassName</param-name>
        <param-value>org.apache.wicket.spring.SpringWebApplicationFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>wicket.filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>7200</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

The only class that use WebApplication is my class MounterURL:

public class MounterURL {

```
private WebApplication webApplication;

public MounterURL(final WebApplication webApplication) {
    this.webApplication = webApplication;
}

/**
 * @param mountPath
 *            Mount path (not empty)
 * @param pageClass
 *            Class of mounted page (not null)
 * @param parameters
 *            The parameter names (not null)
 */
public void mount(final String mountPath,final Class<? extends WebPage> pageClass, final String... parameters) {
    webApplication.mountPage(mountPath, pageClass);
}
```

This class is used by MyApplication :

public class MyApplication extends AuthenticatedWebApplication{

```
private MounterURL aMounterURL;

private GeneralService generalService;

@Override
protected Class<? extends AbstractAuthenticatedWebSession> getWebSessionClass() {
     return WebSession.class;
}

@Override
public Class<? extends Page> getHomePage() {
     return Home.class;
}

public String getContextPath() {
    return this.getServletContext().getContextPath();
}

@Override
public void init() {
    **aMounterURL = new MounterURL(this);**

    this.getComponentInstantiationListeners().add(new SpringComponentInjector(this));

    this.mountUrl("home", Home.class, "");
}

private void mountUrl(final String mountPath, final Class<? extends WebPage> pageClass, final String... parameters) {
    aMounterURL.mount(mountPath, pageClass, parameters);
}
```

This class is created in web.context.xml

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

```
<bean id="wicketApplication" class="home.MyApplication">
    <property name="generalService" ref="services.general"></property>
</bean>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you missing a bean of the type WebApplication. Did you extend Wickets WebApplication class and added it as a bean. e.g with @Configuration?

Comment: The only class i have is public class MyApplication extends AuthenticatedWebApplication

Comment: You have to add it to the Spring context as a bean if you want to use `applicationFactoryClassName=SpringWebApplicationFactory`.

Comment: it is already added                                                                                <bean id="wicketApplication" class="home.MyApplication">
    <property name="generalService" ref="services.general"></property>
</bean> in web-context.xml and web.xml calls it

Comment: I tried this  <init-param>
   <param-name>applicationFactoryClassName</param-name>
   <param-value>home.MyApplication</param-value>
  </init-param>  but is the same

Comment: If you don't want to waste you time with configuration problems of spring and wicket you should look at: https://goo.gl/sy2G62